# Tomcat maximum threads

Tags: tomcat, threadpool

I understand that setting the maximum number of connections available in a connection pool should be the same as your maxThreads configured for your Tomcat server (which correlates to the number of requests that can be handled)

For tomcat the default is 200, I assume there is a maximum that you can safely configure for your Tomcat server before things start getting out of control, which I assume is also governed by the resources of the machine it is running on.

I am trying to get an understanding of the size of maxThreads that people are using with success, is 1000 too big?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there's articles which describe this scientifically but I'll give my opinion instead.

Firstly, I don't set the connection pool conns to equal threads the number of worker threads. There's no pointing having conns pools if you do. The DB server capacity drives this figure but I usually drive for about 50-80% of the worker threads and ensure the DB cluster can handle the load.

The problem is that the more threads you try to handle the more memory you use and the more contention you may have. I try not to run with more than 6GB of heap per JVM and so vertically and horizontally scale do deal with the load.

Unfortunately, only performance testing can help you work out the sweet spot for these figures.